# How to get the clean permalink in a draft?

Tags: permalinks, template-tags, draft

When I use `the_permalink` or `get_the_permalink` in a draft or scheduled post, the URL provided is not the "final" permalink—it is the unpretty `?p=xxxxx` version.

How can I get the final, "clean" permalink to show up in a draft or scheduled post?

I could do something involving `$post->post_name`, but I'd need the path as well, and that varies from post type to post type and depends on permalink structure. Is there a "universal" way to do this?

Comment: Why would you need the pretty permalink for drafts?

Comment: @sanchothefat Among other things, I generate a PDF (containing the post's permalink), before publishing. Now the only way I can do that on an unpublished post is with static text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a little "hacky", but when you call `get_permalink` and you need the permalink for a draft, provide a clone of your post object with the details filled in:

```
global $post;
if ( in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
    $my_post = clone $post;
    $my_post->post_status = 'publish';
    $my_post->post_name = sanitize_title(
        $my_post->post_name ? $my_post->post_name : $my_post->post_title,
        $my_post->ID
    );
    $permalink = get_permalink( $my_post );
} else {
    $permalink = get_permalink();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Since editor displays projected permalink for slug editor, it must have some way to figure it out. From looking at source that is handled by [`get_sample_permalink_html()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_sample_permalink_html/) and [`get_sample_permalink()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_sample_permalink/).

Since we only need link without form cruft, we can rework it into something like:

```
function get_draft_permalink( $post_id ) {

    require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/post.php';
    list( $permalink, $postname ) = get_sample_permalink( $post_id );

    return str_replace( '%postname%', $postname, $permalink );
}
```

No confidence it is foolproof, but works fine from quick test. :)

Comment: FYI, I had to change it to `str_replace( '%pagename%', $postname, $permalink )` for WooCommerce products, not sure if this is needed for WordPress posts as well.