# Get (eventual) permalink from post within Edit Post in Admin panel

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, wp-admin, shortlink

I'm working on a plugin that needs to access grab the Permalink from within the Edit Post screen to send it to a link-shortener API. The catch is that I will need to grab the permalink before the post has been published (while it's in Draft state). So for instance, if I have a post titled "My New Post" and it's a draft and its post ID is 2048, my permalink currently shows with `mydomain.com/?p=2048` instead of `mydomain.com/my-new-post` if I use `<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_id()); ?>`

I need a function that can grab the permalink that is displayed at the top of the Edit Post admin page which matches `mydomain.com/my-new-post`.

Can anyone suggest a way of accessing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**get_post_permalink** won't work for draft or pending posts. But there are a couple workarounds you could use.

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41588/how-to-get-the-clean-permalink-in-a-draft) there is a similar post with two options.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns:

```http://example.com/?post_type=post&p=2084``` not the desired ```http://exmaple.com/my-new-post```

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand the documentation. [Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41588/how-to-get-the-clean-permalink-in-a-draft) there is a similar post with two options.

Comment: That fixed it! Can you edit your initial comment so I can mark as answer?